# jquery ajax doesn't work when I use recursion with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, recursion

I have a problem using ajax (jquery) and recursion. I call a php script which contains a recursive function. I don't know what's happening but I got this error everytime I call the $ajax function:

```
POST **myURL** 500 (Internal Server Error)
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send  jquery.min.js:4
f.extend.ajax                        jquery.min.js:4
$.ajax                               jquery.validate.js:1068
myfunction                           file.php:216
(anonymous function)                 file.php:1
onclick
```

Comment: it means that the ajax is not the source of the problem. deal with it in the server-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your server logs to see what error is happening. Whenever you get a 500 error, it means that your server did receive data from the browser, but something went wrong in the server code. In other words, the problem isn't something in the browser code (i.e. it isn't jQuery/Javascript), so take a look at the server logs to see what's happening there.

Comment: Yes the server did receive the data, because in the PHP script (the one that causes the 500 error) before the recursive function execution I have a query (a delete) and the process goes well until it gets in the recursive function.

Comment: I think the problem is something called "segmentation fault".... http://bitdepth.thomasrutter.com/2010/05/16/php-recursion-causes-segmentation-fault/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my script, I just want to recommend everyone "BACK TO BASICS". I spent 4 hours trying to fix it (I thought it was a recursion problem) and finally I found the mistake: it was a **syntax problem** in my php script.